# Notepad++ How to remove line without 2 space character

Tags: regex, notepad++

I can remove line without 1 space character with notepad++

```
^[^ ]*$
```

How to remove line without 2 space character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match a line that does not contain 2 spaces, you could use a negative lookahead asserting not 2 times a space using `\S*` to match zero or more times a non whitespace char.

```
^(?!\S* \S* \S*$).+$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right is not

  - `\S* \S* \S*$` Match 2 spaces between 0+ non whitespace chars `\S*`
- `)` Close lookahead
- `.+` Match any char 0+ times except a newline
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ei8QwV/1)

Answer (score 0):

I guess, maybe you want to remove lines with 1 space and 3 or more, maybe then

```
^ {1}$|^ {3,}$
```

might be OK to look into.

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/zFmGfP/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/zFmGfP/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]